# Has Evergrande defaulted or not?

Tags: china

so many news headlines harbinger [evergrande's default](https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/47614)! today, dec 9 2021, bloomberg reports [Evergrande Declared in Default as Huge Restructuring Looms](https://www.bloomberg.com/news/articles/2021-12-09/evergrande-defaults-for-first-time-as-china-debt-strains-spread). but scroll down!

> Even Fitch has struggled to get information from Evergrande, noting on Thursday that the developer didn’t respond to its request for confirmation on this week’s coupon payments. “We are therefore assuming they were not paid,” Fitch analysts wrote in a statement. Bloomberg reported earlier this week that bondholders hadn’t received the money.

so fitch is JUST "assuming" evergrande defaulted. but this doesn't prove evergrande defaulted!!!!

Comment: There is no need to keep us updated on the news, this site is not about that. Please focus on posting clear & on-topic questions.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*Default* is also a legal concept, and as such it is sometimes debatable whether an entity is in the state of default or not.

E.g., see [Greece debt crisis: when is a default not a default?](https://www.theguardian.com/business/2015/jun/30/greece-debt-crisis-default-analysis-imf)